# Store parts of huge ByteBuffer to file

Tags: android, memory-management, io

I have implemented a loop buffer (or circular buffer) storing 250 frames raw video data in total (frame resolution 1280x720). As a buffer I am using the `ByteBuffer` class. The buffer is running in a separate thread using a Looper, every new frame is passed via a message to the thread `Handler` object. When the limit is reached, the position is set to 0 and the whole buffer is overwritten from the beginning. Like that, the buffer always contains the last 250 video frames.

As the amount of required heap space is huge (around 320 MByte) I am using the tag `android:largeHeap="true"` in the manifest.

Now we come to the problem. The loop is running well, it consumes slightly less than the allowed heap space size (which is acceptable for me). But at some point of time, I want to store the whole buffer to a raw binary file while respecting the current position of the buffer.

Let me explain that with a small graph:

The loop buffer looks like this:

|========== HEAD ==========|===============TAIL============|

0 -------------------------`buffer.position()`-----------------------`buffer.limit()`

At the time of saving, I want to first store the tail to the file (because it contains the beginning of the video) and afterwards the head until the current `buffer.position()`. I cannot allocate any more byte arrays for extracting the data from the `ByteBuffer` (heap space is full), thus, I have to directly write the `ByteBuffer` to the file.

At the moment `ByteBuffer` does only allow to be written to a file completely (`write()` method.) Does anybody know what could be the solution? Or is there even a better solution for my task?

I will give my code below:

```
public class FrameRecorderThread extends Thread {

public int MAX_NUMBER_FRAMES_QUEUE = 25 * 10; // 25 fps * 10 seconds
public Handler frameHandler;

private ByteBuffer byteBuffer;
byte[] image =  new byte[1382400]; // bytes for one image

@Override
public void run() {
    Looper.prepare();
    byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(MAX_NUMBER_FRAMES_QUEUE * 1382400); // A lot of memory is allocated
    frameHandler = new Handler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            // Store message content (byte[]) to queue 

            if(msg.what == 0) { // STORE FRAME TO BUFFER
                if(byteBuffer.position() < MAX_NUMBER_IMAGES_QUEUE * 1382400) {
                    byteBuffer.put((byte[])msg.obj);
                }
                else {
                    byteBuffer.position(0); // Start overwriting from the beginning
                }   
            }

            else if(msg.what == 1) { // SAVE IMAGES

                String fileName = "VIDEO_BUF_1.raw";    
                File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                + "/FrameRecorder/");
                directory.mkdirs();

                try {
                    FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                    + "/FrameRecorder/" + fileName);

                    // This is the current position of the split between head and tail
                    int position = byteBuffer.position();

                    try {
                        // This stores the whole buffer in a file but does
                        // not respect the order (tail before head)
                        outStream.getChannel().write(byteBuffer);

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }       
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    Log.e("FMT", "File not found. (" + e.getLocalizedMessage() + ")");
                }
            }
            else if(msg.what == 2) { // STOP LOOPER
                Looper looper = Looper.myLooper();
                if(looper != null) {
                    looper.quit();
                    byteBuffer = null;
                    System.gc();
                }
            }
        }
    };
    Looper.loop();
}}
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, in the meanwhile I have investigated a little further and found a solution.

Instead of a `ByteBuffer` object I am using a simple `byte[]` array. In the beginning I am allocating all heap space required for the frames. At the time of storing it, I can then write the head and tail of the buffer by using the current position. This works and is easier than expected. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just create a subsection and write that to a file.

Or call set Length and then write it and then set it back.

Comment: Could you give me an example please? Generating a subsection is exactly the problem here, so I do not know how to do it.

Comment: Just create a new one with the offset and length desired using the old one as the src.

Comment: I cannot do that, because I would need to allocate memory for that. Unfortunately the heap space is full. But I could try to do it byte-wise. Or is there any better solution?

Comment: Call length (size),  write the chunk, then call flip ()